# R code: How to calculate the number of times a number is exceeded (or below) in a list

Tags: r, list

I have a list with water table measurements for 2-4 years and want to calculate the number of times a certain water table is exceeded (e.g. -0.22) or fallen below (second step).

I tried it with:

```
sum(abs(Mylist <= -0.22) < 1e-6)
```

but R answers `'not senseful for factors'`

What is the correct way to solve this problem?

Here is a link to the data:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/oq9v7nbg7baadm8/QmDuVpTk2v

I would be very grateful for hints!

Comment: `cleaned <- as.numeric(as.character(Mylist))` should return values that you can apply `abs` to - if there are any missing values, then _Mylist_ contains things that aren't numbers. When you've got that, `sum(cleaned >= -0.22 | cleaned < 1e6)` seems to reflect what you want in the text

Comment: What is the structure of `Mylist`? Is it truly a `list` or is it perhaps a `vector`?

Comment: Thanks guys, yeah probably Roman is right, it is a vector with 327 variables plus date and 1500 rows (with water tables). The command hint from Gavin resulted in a warning 'NAs produced while conversion' but no changes in MyList, only a new value called clean with 327 NAs in it.

Comment: You are more likely to get useful help if you upload your data somewhere (Dropbox?) and post a link in your question. Then we can see what's actually going on.

Comment: Here is a link to the txt file: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/oq9v7nbg7baadm8/QmDuVpTk2v

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
library(lubridate)

df = fread("/storage/Downloads/Watertable_fluctuations_All_Original.txt", 
     skip = 1, header = T) # dropbox file
df = df[, date := dmy(date)]

dfm = melt(df, id.vars = "date", value.name = "water.level")

wl.threshold = -0.22

dfm[water.level < wl.threshold,.N, keyby = variable] # count per measuring station

# bonus
library(openair)
timePlot(dfm[variable == "Yel342(2010)"],
     pollutant = "water.level", 
     smooth = T, 
     ref.y = wl.threshold)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, tried it and R reports problem in `[.data.frame`(dfm, water.level < wl.threshold, .N, keyby = variable) : 
  unbenutztes Argument (keyby = variable)- unused argument
For the plot: R reports: probkem in `[.data.frame`(dfm, variable == "Yel342(2010)") : object 'variable' not found - But it is there in dfm!
May it be connected to the fact that I use RStudio for Mac?

Comment: Check that both dfm and df are data.table by typing in tables(). You can make the key explicit by: setkey(dfm,variable); dfm[water.level < wl.threshold,.N, by = key(dfm)].

Comment: > tables(df)
Fehler in if (mb) { : 
  Argument kann nicht als logischer Wert interpretiert werden
Zusätzlich: Warnmeldung:
In if (mb) { :
  Bedingung hat Länge > 1 und nur das erste Element wird benutzt
Can you help?

Comment: It seems that the data.table library is not working well on your computer. [did you install.packages("data.table") and library(data.table)? ]. I can run the code without any problems on a Linux Ubuntu system. It is probably best to open a separate question, with tag data.table. There are several data.table gurus and they are very responsive.

Comment: Yeah, installed it and checked it. Ok thanks a lot! I will do so. Great to have the possibility to ask you guys!